# How to search w2ui date between

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, w2ui

I have table using w2ui javascript with the data json in the record. I can't search by date using operator between, **this code it's not working**. But it's working when I using operator is and with one parameter. I don't know what wrong with this code. What I miss?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#grid').w2grid({
    name: 'grid',
    columns: [
      { field: 'recid', caption: 'ID', size: '50px', sortable: true }, 
      { field: 'fname', caption: 'First Name', size: '30%', sortable: true },
      { field: 'lname', caption: 'Last Name', size: '30%', sortable: true }, 
      { field: 'email', caption: 'Email', size: '40%' }, 
      { field: 'sdate', caption: 'Start Date', size: '120px', render:'date', type: 'date' }],
    records: [{
      recid: 1,
      fname: 'John',
      lname: 'doe',
      email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
      sdate: '4/3/2012'
    }, {
      recid: 2,
      fname: 'Stuart',
      lname: 'Motzart',
      email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
      sdate: '4/3/2012'
    }, {
      recid: 3,
      fname: 'Jin',
      lname: 'Franson',
      email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
      sdate: '4/3/2012'
    }, {
      recid: 4,
      fname: 'Susan',
      lname: 'Ottie',
      email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
      sdate: '4/3/2012'
    }, {
      recid: 5,
      fname: 'Kelly',
      lname: 'Silver',
      email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
      sdate: '4/3/2012'
    }, {
      recid: 6,
      fname: 'Francis',
      lname: 'Gatos',
      email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
      sdate: '4/3/2012'
    }, {
      recid: 7,
      fname: 'Mark',
      lname: 'Welldo',
      email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
      sdate: '4/3/2012'
    }, {
      recid: 8,
      fname: 'Thomas',
      lname: 'Bahh',
      email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
      sdate: '4/7/2012'
    }, {
      recid: 9,
      fname: 'Sergei',
      lname: 'Rachmaninov',
      email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
      sdate: '4/6/2012'
    }, {
      recid: 10,
      fname: 'Jill',
      lname: 'Doe',
      email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
      sdate: '4/5/2012'
    }]
  });
  
});

function search1() {
    w2ui['grid'].search([{ field: 'sdate', value: ['4/5/2012', '4/7/2012'], type: 'date', operator: 'between'}]);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://w2ui.com/src/w2ui-1.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://w2ui.com/src/w2ui-1.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"></div>
<br />
Date: <input type="text" name="sDate"> <input type="text" name="eDate">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="search1()">
```

Comment: i think problem is about date format.

Comment: can you fix it? i don't know what fomat do you mind @YiğitYüksel

Answer (score 0):

Search property has to be defined by type for each columns

eg.

```
 searches: [
            { field: 'recid', caption: 'ID ', type: 'int' },
            { field: 'lname', caption: 'Last Name', type: 'text' },
            { field: 'fname', caption: 'First Name', type: 'text' },
            { field: 'email', caption: 'Email', type: 'list', options: { items:[ 'jim@gmail.com', 'jdoe@gmail.com']} },
            { field: 'sdate', caption: 'Start Date', type: 'date' }
 ],
```